# Analytics dashboards sort TableChart

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

In API Store statistics I have created a gadget to sort API requests details. The data exposed are in a persisted stream (table), populated by a stream that groups data by date.

The data shown in the gadget (TableChart) are sorted by date in ascending order, so the oldest records are shown for firsts; the limit of records imposed in `js/core/batch-provider-api.js` does that newest records are never shown.

Is it possible to define an `order by` clause to retreive the most recent data as the first?